# How do I output an array so that it can be copy pasted back in to code?

Tags: php, arrays

If you want to ask for help with an array (here on SO for example) you need to post the array for others to see.
The problem is there is no good way to output an array so that it can be copy pasted back in to a php code.
Many users just dump their array and it becomes a mess and/or hard for those who want to help to fix the array so it can be used.

If you use var_dump the result will be

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "string"
    [1]=>
    int(1)
    ["return"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["two"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-10-09"
    [1]=>
    float(248.38)
    ["return"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [3]=>
  float(-123.4)
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "foo"
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "bar"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You end up with extra strings like *string(6)* that has to be removed. And the commas are missing between new items.

Print_r solves *string(6)* but it's still missing the commas, strings and associative keys are missing "".

Is there any good method to output your array that you can just copy paste to SO?
I have answered this question myself but if anyone have a better way or know how to make my code better, **feel free to copy it and use what you need.**
I think it's better that we have a good code we can make askers use in order to format their arrays than limit answers in this thread due to copyright.
Again, feel free to copy my code and make it better if you can, **but for others answers in this thread normal rules apply unless other is stated.**

Expected result would be an array formatted in such way that you can copy paste it in a php code and it will run directly without any adding or deleting.

Example array:

```
$arr =Array(
    0 => Array
        (
            0 => "string",
            1 => 1,
            "return" => true
        ),

    "two" => Array
        (
            0 => "2017-10-09",
            1 => 248.38,
            "return" => false
        ),
    3 => -123.4,
    4 => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => "foo",
                1 => array(
                    0 => "bar"
                    )
                )
        )
);
```

Comment: `var_export()`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Comment: I had no clue there was a third way. I searched for it but I didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: How can it be that you didn't find it, but still used `var_export` in your answer to format a boolean value? Puzzled...

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

```
var_export($arr);
```

For the array you provide at the start of your question, this outputs:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'string',
    1 => 1,
    'return' => true,
  ),
  'two' => 
  array (
    0 => '2017-10-09',
    1 => 248.38,
    'return' => false,
  ),
  3 => -123.40000000000001,
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'foo',
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => 'bar',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Note the minor "glitch" following from the known floating point accuracy problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is the best I can do.
There is one extra comma I can't seem to get ridd of in my example array.
I have a function that echo the keys and values. It indents four spaces at the first level and for each level it adds four spaces.
I use str_pad to pad with spaces and loop through the with foreach.
See it in action here: https://3v4l.org/AOC0L
The extra comma is after "bar" value.

```
$arr =Array(
    0 => Array
        (
            0 => "string",
            1 => 1,
            "return" => true
        ),

    "two" => Array
        (
            0 => "2017-10-09",
            1 => 248.38,
            "return" => false
        ),
    3 => -123.4,
    4 => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => "foo",
                1 => array(
                    0 => "bar"
                    )
                )
        )
);

echo "<pre>";    
printArray($arr        // Input array for output
           , "array("  // type of output "array()" or "[]". Usage: "array(" or "["
           , 1         // start padding multiplied with 4. 1 = 4 spaces indenting at start.
           , false     // is input a subarray. Always false when you call the function. Only function itself should change this
           );

function printArray($arr, $output, $pad, $subarray){
    // If it's a subarray don't indent "array" text
    if($subarray){
        echo str_pad("", 0, " ") . $output ."<br>\n";
    }else{
        echo str_pad("", $pad*4, " ") . $output ."<br>\n";
    }

    $i=1;
    foreach($arr as $key => $item){
        if(is_array($item)){
            echo str_pad("", ($pad+1)*4, " ");
            // add "" to key if it's associative
            if(is_string($key)){
                echo "\"" . $key. "\" => ";
            }else{
                echo $key . " => ";
            }
            // recrusive run printArray with padding +1 (more indenting)
            printArray($item, $output, $pad+1, true);
        }else{
            echo str_pad("", ($pad+1)*4, " ");

            // add "" to key if it's associative
            if(is_string($key)){
                echo "\"" . $key. "\"";
            }else{
                echo $key;
            }

            // echo item with "" if it's string, or as bool or else as numeric (float/int)
            if(is_string($item)){
                echo " => \"". $item ."\"";
            }else if(is_bool($item)){
                $bool = var_export($item,true);
                echo " => ". $bool;
            }else{
                echo " => ". $item;
            }

            // if it's the last item, don't add comma to end of array
            if($i == count($arr)){
                echo "<br>\n";
            }else{
                echo ",<br>\n";
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }

    // add correct closing bracket
    if($output == "["){
        echo str_pad("", $pad*4, " ") . "]";
    }else{
        echo str_pad("", $pad*4, " ") . ")";
    }

    // if it's the very last item add a ; instead of ,
    if($pad == 1){
        echo ";<br>\n";
    }else{
        if($i == count($arr)){
                echo "<br>\n";
            }else{
                echo ",<br>\n";
            }
    }
```

Output:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "string",
        1 => 1,
        "return" => true
    ),
    "two" => array(
        0 => "2017-10-09",
        1 => 248.38,
        "return" => false
    ),
    3 => -123.4,
    4 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => "foo",
            1 => array(
                0 => "bar"
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: The space padding is purely cosmetic, and the extra comma doesn't have any adverse effect at all, so why not simply use `var_export($arr)` rather than this excessively complex code?

Comment: True. But the padding makes it readable.

Comment: This does not deal with objects. Reinventing the wheel will often give you one of less quality.